# передача композициям указателя их носителя

Tags: c++, композиция

есть класс с некими числовыми полями h и w , класс так же содержит композиции. А есть ли возможность в методе каждой из композиций получить доступ к полям h и w класса который их содержит?

```
class circle {
int radius;
int x;
int y;

public:
circle(int x, int y, int r,){
...
}
void draw () {
/*тут каким-то образом надо использовать h и w от "носителя композиции" */

}


}

class figura1 {
int h;
int w;
circle c1;
circle c2;
circle c3;


public:
figura1(int w, int h) {
  this->w=w;this->h=h;
}

void drawfigura {
    с1.draw();
    с2.draw();
    с3.draw();
}



}
```

усугубляется это тем , что классов подобных fugura1 у меня много (fugura1 ,fugura2, fugura3... , fuguraN ). они отличаются разным количеством композиций circle , а так же помимо circle есть ещё другие примитивы : rectangle, triangle. в них тоже надо передавать ссылку или указатель "носителя" композиции

Comment: Можно создать конструктор который будет принимать ссылку на родителя и хранить ее в поле

Comment: @SelfishCrawler можно и так. а разве можно this передать в конструкторе figura1 в композиции ? сейчас попробую.

Comment: @SelfishCrawler нет вы знаете так не пойдет ) дело в том , что классов подобных fugura1 у меня много. они отличаются разным количеством композиций circle , а так же помимо circle есть ещё ractangle, triangle. (обратил внимание на это в вопросе )

Comment: Тогда сделайте поля публичными, либо метод-геттер, если нужно только чтение поля

Comment: Множество circle можно хранить в массиве и инициализировать циклом, как вариант. Либо сделать базовый класс Primitive в котором будет только ссылка на вашу фигуру и конструктор ее принимающий, а от него наследники rectangle triangle итд

Comment: @АндрейГуренков, Вероятно, я ошибаюсь, но есть ощущение, что Вы что-то неудачно придумали с точки зрения проектирования. Может, расскажете ,что Вы хотите сделать?

Comment: @Юрий да тут букв не хватит к сожалению. кажется товарищ выше дело говорит. попробую. спасибо

Comment: Класс базовый с размерами `class HW{int h,w;};` и предки : `class figura1:public HW{...};` Фигурам `circle` , ... передавать ссылку только на базовый класс с размерами `HW`.

Comment: @AlexGlebe  я уже понял. это же и предлагал SelfishCrawler

Comment: Я усовершенствовал, предлагаю **один** базовый тип, а не много.

Comment: @AlexGlebe ну я так сразу и понял ))

Comment: @AlexGlebe  а вот и не вышло или я все ж не понял))) как ты собрался инициализировать композиции ? тебе ведь их надо в конструкторе фигуры инициализоровать значениями наверно как this (или чем тогда ?) . а компилятор в этом случае отругает : мол попытка подсунуть указатель на базовый тип как указатель на предка

Comment: Преобразование указателя на родителя `HW` тихо и спокойно разрешается, он за всё заплатит. А на сына нет. Нужно доказать, что это твой сын в натуре.

Comment: @AlexGlebe как сделать указатель на родителя ?

Comment: @AlexGlebe  всё , отбой . я утупок )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот добавил этот базовый. Всё компилируется.

```
class HW  {
protected :
  int h ;
  int w ;
public :
  int H()const{return h;}
  int W()const{return w;}
} ;

class circle {
int radius;
int x;
int y;
HW * hw { nullptr } ;

public:
circle  ( HW * const dim  ) : hw  ( dim ) { }
circle(int x, int y, int r){
//...
}
void draw () {
/*тут каким-то образом надо использовать h и w от "носителя композиции" */
  if ( x < hw -> W() )
    if ( y < hw -> H() )
      ;

}


} ;

class figura1 : public HW {

// перенесли
// int h;
// int w;

// здесь автоматически указатель this
//  конвертируется на базовый HW
circle c1 { this } ;
circle c2 { this } ;
circle c3 { this } ;


public:
figura1(int w, int h) {
  this->w=w;this->h=h;
}

void drawfigura (){
  c1.draw();
  c2.draw();
  c3.draw();
}

} ;
```

Comment: ну да. моя ошибка была , что я пытался сделать не указателем , а ссылкой вот тут circle  ( HW * const dim  )

Comment: ссылкой тоже можно. Но сразу только с наличием hw. `HW & hw ; public : circle  ( HW & dim  ) : hw  ( dim ) { } `.. `circle c1 { * this } ;`